# C# Using the selected item in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, combobox, selecteditem

Folks.
I have a problem with a combobox. I have a form with this combobox and when I select one item there I must use it to create a new record which will be inserted in a table. The items in the ComboBox are inserted with
CB_Oper.Items.Add("Item1");
and so on. There is no table associated to this ComboBox. How can I know which is the selected item in the ComboBox? I tried to use ValueMember, but it didn't work.
Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Comment: Which Framework?

Comment: We cannot help you without seeing some code

Comment: You need to use SelectedItem property of Combobox.

Comment: Here you are not setting any ValueMember to the combobox. If you have a value associated to each item, you can try a dictionary as a DataSource to the combobox.

Comment: Hi, Folks. I tried Chetan's suggestion and it appears that it worked. I was using the wrong option. Thanks to you all.